# Why does Kingo Root app need network access?

Tags: rooting

I installed the Kingo Root (aka KingoRoot) APK on my Android device and launched the app. My phone was on airplane mode and I saw the screen

> Kingo ROOT
>
> Please make sure your network connection is stable and try again.

What exactly beyond the app itself does the app need to root the device that requires network access?

Comment: thx but this is common sense, furthermore such rooting methods are long outdated meanwhile ;)

Comment: I once rooted a device using Kingo Root. It installed a ton of extremely sketchy and borderline malicious adware. Would not recommend. Use Magisk if you can unlock your bootloader.

Comment: I was following along with this guy's tutorial [Windows--Android Acquisition using ADB, root, ncat and DD](https://youtu.be/KKkvkCgMeMA?t=313)

Answer (score 19):

Not sure entirely, but this may be the reason why

> KingoRoot was banned from the XDA Developers forum along with vRoot in November 2013 due to concerns with the information collected by the app during the rooting process.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingo_Root

> Ragnar (Retired Forum Moderator)
> Nov 6, 2013 at 3:02 PM
>
> Be aware that as of this moment XDA has deemed the Kingo root method and Vroot method are not allowed on XDA. There are concerns with the information which is collected during the root method by the exploit. It is not about a continuous malware which may affect your device but about important information shared about your device, serial numbers etc during the root process which could be huge securities issues.
>
> You have all been warned
>
> Thread closed. If you have any questions regarding this please contact myself or any other moderator via PM
>
> https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kingoapp.2503591/page-3

Another suggestion is server access is needed to cross reference your device to a list of possible exploits that can be employed on it...

> Kingo root download exploit from their server
>
> [https://www.quora.com/What-things-exactly-does-Kingo-Root-do-for-rooting](https://www.quora.com/What-things-exactly-does-Kingo-Root-do-for-rooting#:%7E:text=There%20are%20some%20exploits%20(read%20as%20c%2B%2B%20code)%20available%20for%20most%20of%20Android%20versions%20which%20is%20used%20for%20rooting.%20Kingo%20root%20download%20exploit%20from%20their%20server.)

And this guy highlights a bunch of app permissions, bolding the privacy oriented ones for offloading user data to a remote server

> it has its own service running in background which maybe pushing your data to their servers
>
> https://www.quora.com/Is-KingRoot-the-one-tap-Chinese-rooting-app-legit-and-safe/answer/Faiyyaz-Shaikh

Comment: It also installs adware lol